# Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid locale

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, locale, postgresql-12

To resolve postgresql conflicts (see my previous question), I've installed postgre-common `brew install petere/postgresql/postgresql-common` and postgre@12. Then create my cluster `pg_createcluster 12 main`.

There's already a content in the local DB, created 1 year ago, which I can no more access, because environment postgre 11 cannot acces DB initialized with postgre 12.

But  when I launch `pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`.
Cluster was created successfully, appears on list `pg_lscluster`, can be dropped with `pg_dropcluster` and recreated susscessfully :

```
    pg_ctlcluster 12 main start  
     background-jobs-demo git:(master) ✗ pg_createcluster 12 main
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 12/main ...
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main --auth-local peer --auth-host md5
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "pierre".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Paris
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    '/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_ctl' -D /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l logfile start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner  Data directory                        Log file
12  main    5432 down   pierre /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main /usr/local/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

But cluster doesn't start.

```
Error: /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /usr/local/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/usr/local/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf" -c external_pid_file="/usr/local/var/run/postgresql/12-main.pid"  exited with status 1: 
2021-12-04 22:44:50.632 CET [76694] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.9 (Homebrew petere/postgresql) on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2), 64-bit
2021-12-04 22:44:50.636 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2021-12-04 22:44:50.636 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-12-04 22:44:50.638 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-12-04 22:44:50.651 CET [76694] FATAL:  postmaster became multithreaded during startup
2021-12-04 22:44:50.651 CET [76694] HINT:  Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid locale.
2021-12-04 22:44:50.652 CET [76694] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

On my shell, the locales values are

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

How shall I set locale LC_ALL value for postgresql@12 ?

The helpful link https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/317#issuecomment-251786830 is for postgre9.6, and I can't find how to set locale LC_ALL value for postgresql@12.

I've tried different things that didn't work :

- add `lc_all='C'` or `lc_all='en_US.UTF-8'`
  in `/usr/local/var/postgresql@12/postgresql.conf`,
- add `lc_all='C'`
  in `/usr/local/var/postgresql@12/postgresql.conf`,

Comment: 1) That issue also mentions problems with the AV software Cylance. Do you have that installed? 2) `lc_all` cannot be set `postgresql.conf` 3) What happens if you do `brew services start postgresql`?

Comment: No AV Cylance doesn't soudn to me.

Comment: What does `pg_lsclusters` return? At the moment there is no data in your database correct? If so what happens when you do: 1) `pg_dropcluster 12 main` 2) `pg_createcluster 12 main`. In this step what is the information returned, in particular the value for `LC_ALL`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've added these informations in my question :) three interesting lines about locales

Comment: If your existing data is in a Postgres 11 cluster why are you installing Postgres 12? Also how was the Postgres 11 version installed and does the data directory still exist?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver PostgreSQL initialized version 12 incompatible with 11.14 . As far as I undestood, I must access with v12 to access DB initialized v12. Did I misinterpret ? The data directory surely still exists, but I can't access it due to this error, how can I check ?

Comment: Hmm, found this [Issue  #643](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/643) from PostgresApp that indicates it may actually be an `SSL` issue on OS X 10.12, which I believe is what you are running. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Installing Postgres 12 will not allow you to access the data directory created by the 11 version of Postgres.  What did you use to install the Postgres 11 version originally?

Comment: Bundle install. My current postgre version was 11.14.1 when I got these errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239857/discussion-between-pierrecode-and-adrian-klaver).

Comment: The command `locale -a` show you the installed locales (and with the recommended name). Default docker images often do not include any locales but C (so you must install locales). `LC_ALL` should be uppercase (env variables are case sensitive)

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoCatenazzi do you know which file must be added LC_ALL value ? ➜  postgres locale -a
af_ZA
...
ko_KR.UTF-8
lt_LT
lt_LT.ISO8859-13
lt_LT.ISO8859-4
lt_LT.UTF-8
nl_BE
...
zh_TW.UTF-8
C
POSIX

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi this situation does not involve Docker. I'm pretty sure it is not actually a `locale` issue as Postgres 11 does install per the discussion in the chat. I'm leaning more to this [Issue 643](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/643).  The `LC_ALL` value is already set in your case.